# How do i fix this error: undefined reference to `distance(float, float, float, float)'

Tags: c++, undefined

So I am not really sure what to do here, I have gone back over my code multiple times and it all seems to be right but I keep getting the error code

Stubblefield9.cpp:74: undefined reference to `distance(float, float, float, float)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is my code if anyone can help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const float pi=3.14;
int choice;
char again;

   do
   {
       cout << "  IHCC Computer Science Registration Menu\n";
       cout << "  ======================================\n";
       cout << "  1.  The Volume of a Cone\n";
       cout << "  2.  The Volume of a Sphere\n";
       cout << "  3.  The Area of an Octagon\n";
       cout << "  4.  The Destance between two Points\n";
       cout << "  ======================================\n";
       cout << "  Enter your selection: ";

cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    float coneRadius,coneHeight,coneVolume;
    cout<<"Enter the Radius of the cone:";
    cin>>coneRadius;
    cout<<"\nEnther the Height of the Cone: ";
    cin>>coneHeight;
    coneVolume=pi*coneRadius*coneRadius*coneHeight/3;
    cout<<"\nThe Volume of a Cone with Radius ("<< coneRadius << ") and  Height (" << coneHeight << setprecision(2) << fixed << ") is " << coneVolume;
break;
case 2:
float sphereRadius,sphereVolume;
   cout << "Please insert the Radius: ";
   cin >>sphereRadius;
   sphereVolume = (4/3)*(pi)*(sphereRadius*sphereRadius*sphereRadius);
   cout<<"Volume with radius "<< setprecision(1) << fixed << sphereRadius << setprecision(2) << fixed << " is "<<sphereVolume;
break;
case 3:
float octagonSide, octagonArea;
cout << "Input side length: ";
 cin >> octagonSide;
octagonArea =(2 * (1 + sqrt(2)) * octagonSide * octagonSide); 
cout << "\nThe area of the octagon with side length (" << octagonSide << setprecision(2) << fixed << ") is "<< octagonArea;

break;
case 4:
float x, y, a, b, answer;

  float distance(float x, float y, float a, float b);
       cout << "Enter the points for the coordinates";
       cout << endl;
       cout << "Point x for first coordinates: ";
       cin >> x;
       cout << endl;
       cout << endl;
       cout << "Point y for first coordinate: ";
       cin >> y;
       cout << endl;
       cout << endl;
          cout << "Point x for the second coordinate: ";
       cin >> a;
       cout << endl;
       cout << endl;
       cout << "Point y for the second coordinate: ";
       cin >> b;
       cout << endl;
       cout << endl;
       answer = distance(x, y, a, b);
       cout << "The answer is " << answer;
break;
default:
cout << "Not a Valid Choice. \n";
cout << "Choose again.\n";
cin >> choice;
break ;
}
     cout << "\n\n Would you like to do it again(y or n)";
     cin >> again;
  }  while( again == 'y' || again == 'Y' );
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you try to call a function `distance()` that is declared in your code by

> `float distance(float x, float y, float a, float b);`

but not defined.

Comment: Sorry, but thats not a question to ask on StackOverflow, but to be answered by your favourite C++ textbook.

Comment: @RayStubblefield You **define** it by providing a body for the function defining what it does, e.g. `float distance(float x, float y, float a, float b) { /* do something with x, y, a, b */ }`. A **declaration** let's the compiler know that this function is defined somewhere, the **definition** provides the code that does that.

Comment: float distance(float x, float y, float a, float b); is a function prototype and typically declared in a .h file and not in a switch case, looks like a "copy and paste" error .

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what do you mean by do something with them? sorry I am not very good at programming

Comment: @RayStubblefield what is the function `distance()` supposed to do? From its signature its clear that it takes four `float`s and returns a `float` ... but what does/should it do?

Comment: Well, what does `distance()` do? You seem to be passing `(x,y)` and `(a,b)` coordinate pairs, so I would presume that `distance()` would calculate the distance between the two points. "Do something" means do the calculation and then `return result;`. (note I would recommend changing all types from `float` to `double` to minimize rounding.)

Comment: It should calculate the distance between the two coordinate points.'sqrt(pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2));'

Comment: @RayStubblefield then "`/* do something with x, y, a, b */`" should be replaced with the calculation to do that.

Comment: double distance( double x,double y,double a,double b);{sqrt(pow(x - a, 2) + pow(y - b, 2));} so like this?

Comment: @RayStubblefield Maybe. However, your function has to `return` something.

Comment: so at the end of that do `return answer` ?

Comment: @RayStubblefield I am not sure what `answer` is supposed to be, but if you interpret `distance(foo, bar, baz, qux);` as a question, yes, the function should `return` an answer. Seriously, what material are you learning C++ from??

Comment: The book is introduction to programming with c++ 3rd edition. But this is on me it probably says it in there but I am still just not very good at this coding thing and it still output the same error code

Comment: @RayStubblefield Then you should probably re-read the chapter about functions again.